# Charge inside spherical shell with dielectric between plates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, induction, dielectric

I'm asking help for this exercise.

> Charge $q$ is surrounded by two thin spherical conducting shells $C_1$ and $C_2$. The space between $C_1$ and $C_2$ is filled with dielectric of constant $k$. If $q_1=-2q$ is put on $C_1$ and $q_2=3q$ is put on $C_2$ (both from infinity), what are charges on surface of every spherical shell.

So this is my attempt:

$+q$ is inside so, because of induction, $-q$ charge should be near $C_1$ and so charge on the outer surface of $C_1$ will be $q_1' = -2q - q = -3q$ but the answer is $-q$ and for $C_2$ I thought that dieletric isolate $C_2$ so nothing will happen but the answer is $2q$.

Then in order to calculate $E$, I should use Gauss law for dielectric finding $D$, that is constant thanks to symmetry and then $E$, right?

Can you help me to understand; I'm not very good with dielectric.

----Edit----

Ok, I think I understand:

1. charge $q$ creates induced charge $-q$ on the inner surface that for maintaining $E=0$ in the conductor create induced charge $+q$ on the outer surface. So, the total charge on $C_1$ is $-2q + q = -q$.
2. The charge $-q$ (on the outer surface of $C_1$) creates for induction charge $+q$ on the inner surface that for maintaining $E=0$ in the conductor crate induced charge $-q$ on the outer surface. So the total charge on $C_2$ is $3q + (-q) = 2q$.

Right? *So also if there is a dielectric the charge can be induced and dielectric doesn't change the charge induced?*

Comment: Yes on each surface, sorry.

Comment: You have made an elementary mistake with the outer surface of C1. The total charge on C1 must be -2q. Your calculation has -q on the inner surface and -3q on the outer, a total of -4q.

Comment: sorry i don't understand...if i put -2q on the surface plus -q of induced charge, should charge be -3q on C1 ? and why charge on C2 is 2q?

Comment: Induction does not change the total charge on an isolated conductor. It only changes the distribution of the total charge.

Comment: Sorry but i still don't understand how i should do this problem?

Comment: Why don't you understand? C1 has 2 surfaces. The question tells you the total charge on C1. You have already worked out the charge on the inner surface. It only requires simple arithmetic to work out the charge on the outer surface of C1.

Comment: you mean i have to consider a sphere which have inside charge q + (-2q) and 3q + (-2q) + q?

Comment: It seems the words "maintain" and "dielectric" don't really like you ;-). And, "I" is always uppercase on English. You got my reopen vote, because your question is to me clear, but note, this site mainly unwelcomes homework-like questions ($\approx$ questions like "calculate me this" - it is a different close reason).

Comment: re your edit : No, sorry, you are still getting it wrong. The first part of each of 1 and 2 is correct. But you are incorrect in the second part when you say "the total charge on C1 (C2) is ...". The total charge on each conductor is given in the question. The charges on the inner and outer surfaces of each conductor must add up to the total charge on that conductor. The second part would be correct if you said "The charge on the outer surface is ..."

Comment: Aaah Ok, *-q* and *2q* are the total charge on the **outer surface** and not total charge.

P.S.: sorry i'm not native english and so sometime i forget that _I_ need to be uppercase.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Perhaps the difficulty was that you did not state the question exactly as it is printed. As you have written it, and interpreted it in your 1st comment above, 4 answers are required because there are 4 surfaces. But there are only 2 answers, for the outer surfaces only. Perhaps the question asks "What are the charges on the **outer** surfaces of the two spherical conductors?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made an elementary mistake with the outer surface of C1.

The total charge on C1 must be -2q. Induction does not change the total charge on an isolated conductor. It only changes the distribution of the total charge - in this case, how the total charge is shared between the inner and outer surfaces of C1.

You have already worked out the charge on the inner surface of C1. It only requires simple arithmetic to work out the charge on the outer surface.

Then repeat the same procedure for C2.

The dielectric affects the electric field and the electric potential between C1 and C2, but it does not change the charge on their surfaces.

Comment: whitout dieletric i would do the exercise like this
http://i.imgur.com/ch39GaJ.png

Comment: Is Q the same as q? What is the total charge on C1? And on C2? What are the charges on the outer surface of C1 and the inner surface of C2?

Comment: q, Q(green) and Q(blue) are different charge.
Q(blue) is in the outer surface of C1 and -q in the inner one.
Q(green) is in the outer surface of C2 and +q in the inner one.
So the total charge sould be Q(blue)+(-q) and Q(geren) +(+q).

Comment: In terms of q, what answers do you get now?

Comment: there is for induction charge -q on the inner surface of C1 and, same for induction, +q on the inner surface of C2. The total charge q is **q**

Comment: What about the charges (in terms of q) on the *outer* surfaces of C1 and C2?

Comment: Should be the same value with opposite sign in order to maintain in equilibrium E(between inner and outer surface of conductor) zero but there isn't thickness, the problem say thin spherical conductor, so i think the charge on outer surface is the same on inner.

Comment: I edited the answer...thanks for your help by the way

Comment: If the charge on the outer surface is equal but opposite sign to the charge on the inner surface, then the total charges on C1 and C2 will be zero. Is that what you are saying? That is incorrect : the question says the total charge is -2q for C1 and +3q for C2.

Comment: E=0 inside the plate means that the total charge inside this Gaussian surface is zero. So for C1 the charge +q at the centre is cancelled by the charge -q on the inner surface. Any excess charge must appear on the outer surface.

Comment: i'm talking about induced charge from q.
The charge on C1 is -2q but there is +q induced charge on the outer surface  cause there is -q in the inner one.
Same for C2

Comment: Read my answer : induction does not change the total charge on an isolated conductor. If it is initially 0 it remains 0; if it is initially -2q it remains -2q.

Comment: So:
for C1 =>  q_int1 + q_ext1 = -2q => q_ext1 = -2q - q_int1
for C2 =>  q_int2 + q_ext2 = 3q => q_ext2 = 3q - q_int2
Something like this? Now i'm very confused, what are q_int1 and q_int2?

Comment: You are making this far more complicated than it needs to be. You have already said what the charges are on the inner surfaces of C1 and C2.